# Snowflake - Using JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY to get similar matches in a table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake that has a list of individuals with their addresses. The goal here is to find and link individuals that are potentially the same and allocate the linked records a unique global Identifier. This will unify their transactional activity under a single Id (global Id) or create a winner record and inactivate the others.

Snowflake has a JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY function that can compare the data.

The table DDL statement is

```
create or replace TABLE PH_MATCH_DATA (
    INDIVIDUAL_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(200),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(200),
    GLOBAL_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    ADDRESS_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    ADDRESS_LINE_1 VARCHAR(200),
    ADDRESS_LINE_2 VARCHAR(200),
    CITY VARCHAR(200),
    ADDRESS_POSTAL_AREA_1 VARCHAR(20),
    ADDRESS_POSTAL_AREA_2 VARCHAR(20),
    STATE VARCHAR(4)
);
```

The global Id column is currently null. Below is a query I am experimenting with.

```
select t1.individual_id as individual_id_1, t2.individual_id as individual_id_2
from ph_match_data t1, ph_match_data t2
where t1.individual_id != t2.individual_id
and t1.ADDRESS_POSTAL_AREA_1 = t2.ADDRESS_POSTAL_AREA_1
and JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY(lower(t1.first_name), lower(t2.first_name)) >= 93
and JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY(lower(t1.last_name), lower(t2.last_name)) >= 93
and JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY(lower(t1.ADDRESS_LINE_1), lower(t2.ADDRESS_LINE_1)) >= 93;
```

I would like to get feedback what a correct and efficient approach would be - to detect the dups and essentially link the records.

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 1):

SQL looks fine.

1. You can do little cleanup before matching like remove unwanted char from name before matching names.
2. And increase the score to 95 or more. Because Dan and Daniel can be similar.

```
select t1.individual_id as individual_id_1, t2.individual_id as individual_id_2
from ph_match_data t1, ph_match_data t2
where t1.individual_id != t2.individual_id
and t1.ADDRESS_POSTAL_AREA_1 = t2.ADDRESS_POSTAL_AREA_1
and JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY(regexp_replace(lower(trim(t1.first_name)),'[^a-z0-9]', regexp_replace(lower(trim(t2.first_name)),'[^a-z0-9]') >= 93
and JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY(regexp_replace(lower(trim(t1.last_name)),'[^a-z0-9]', regexp_replace(lower(trim(t2.last_name)),'[^a-z0-9]') >= 93
...
```

Also, please note, JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY is an expensive function and in your case you are using somewhat many-many joins which can take huge resources. I would suggest, create a final table and make an incremental process to load that table whenever there  is some changes to t1 and t2 or periodiccally.

Only thing i would do is